# How to position the dropdown on a multi-line AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am trying to customize the behavior of an `AutoCompleteTextView`, but I have run into some difficulties. My `AutoCompleteTextView` subclass is a multi-line edit text, and I want to be able to vertically position the dropdown (really a `ListPopupWindow`) so as to follow the user's cursor around.

I thought that if I can compute the difference between the top of the anchor view and the current line position, I could set the offset accordingly, but I must be doing something wrong along the way, because the dropdown isn't going quite where I want it to go. Can someone point out to me what I'm doing wrong in this code?

```
    @Override
public void showDropDown() {

    // Get the screen position of the cursor and set the vertical offset accordingly.
    int[] screenPoint = new int[2];
    getLocationOnScreen(screenPoint);

    final Rect displayFrame = new Rect();
    getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(displayFrame);

    int pos = getSelectionStart();
    Layout layout = getLayout();
    int line = layout.getLineForOffset(pos);
    int lineTop = layout.getLineTop(Math.max(0,line - 1));
    int lineBottom = layout.getLineBottom(line);

    int availableSpaceAboveField = screenPoint[1] + lineTop - displayFrame.top;
    int availableSpaceBelowField = displayFrame.bottom - screenPoint[1] - lineBottom;

    int verticalOffset = -lineTop;

    setDropDownVerticalOffset(verticalOffset);
    super.showDropDown();
}
```

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: I'm afraid I have not.